# Javascript:String to date fails

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a date, given as **yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss** to a Javascript Date.

First attemp:

```
var str = "2013-10-31T18:15:30";
var date = new Date(str)
```

Returns **Thu Oct 31 2013 18:15:30 GMT+0100 (CET)**.

Second attemp:

```
var str = "2013-10-31T18:15:30";
var str_parts = str.split("T");
var date_parts = str_parts[0].split("-");
var time_parts = str_parts[1].split(":");
var date = new Date(date_parts[0], date_parts[1], date_parts[2], time_parts[0], time_parts[1], time_parts[2]);
```

Returns **Sun Dec 01 2013 18:15:30 GMT+0100 (CET)**. Do I miss something? Shouldn't this also return **Thu Oct 31 2013 18:15:30 GMT+0100 (CET)**? Somehow, the date is incorrect, while the time fits.

The corresponding fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4CLAj/2/

Comment: I think the month bit in `new Date` is 'zero-based', so it needs to be 9 instead of 10.

Comment: Documentation to the rescue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @putvande: Damn, you're right: **date_parts[1]-1** works correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the Date constructor Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,second) the month is zero-based, i.e. January is zero.

So for the second attempt:

```
var date = new Date(date_parts[0], Number(date_parts[1]) - 1, date_parts[2], time_parts[0], time_parts[1], time_parts[2]);
```

See http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf section 15.9.1.4